# XML file with DTD displays fine in web browser after invalid change

Tags: xml, dtd

I am new to XML and DTD. I have written an XML file with DTD. Here is it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE  note[
     <!ELEMENT note (page , author ,company)>
     <!ELEMENT page (#PCDATA)>
     <!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
     <!ELEMENT company (#PCDATA)>
     <!ATTLIST note type CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>

<note typ="single">
    <page>1000</page>
    <author>devan</author>
    <author>devan</author>
    <company>IDM</company>
</note>
```

It works fine. But my problem is, if you set the `note` attribute as `typ` it displays the result in the web browser just fine. But in the DTD it defines `<!ATTLIST note type CDATA #IMPLIED>`.

And whenever I change the tags in xml `<pag>fhdh </pag>` it displays in the web browser just fine. 
My problem is then why do we define DTD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DTD by itself only defines what a valid XML looks like.

If you run the sample XML in the question through an XML validator, it will **not** be considered valid for the DTD you specified in the question.

Comment: More importantly to the question, it would seem that the web browser is not validating against the DTD.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some reasons ...

http://csharpcomputing.com/XMLTutorial/Lesson8.htm

http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/doctype-declaration.htm

And a PDF:
[DTD for XML](http://www.ischool.utexas.edu/technology/tutorials/webdev/xml_dtds/xml.pdf)