# What is the use of DTD in XML?

Tags: xml, dtd, dtd-parsing

I have write the following XML file with internal DTD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE welcome [
<!ELEMENT welcome (firstname|lastname)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY val "abineshlal">
]>
<welcome>
    <middlename>sm</middlename>
    <firstname>&val;</firstname>
    <lastname>welcome</lastname>
</welcome>
```

I got the output of entity in browser. In my DTD I mentioned only firstname and lastname element in the welcome tag. But I used middle name tag in welcome tag. But I didnt get any error message in output.

I want to the real use of DTD in XML and what it is doing in XML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use DTD in xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061577/why-use-dtd-in-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/DTD/):

> The purpose of a DTD (Document Type Definition) is to define the legal building blocks of an XML document.
>
> A DTD defines the document structure with a list of legal elements and attributes.

You can validate your XML-Document to see if it only uses the by you pre-defined tags in your DTD. This takes away the chance of having wrong data in your XML-Document.

It significantly takes down the amount of errors you can receive when using the Xml-Document, as the node-structure is correct after validating and fixing any faults found.

You can use [this document](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/) to validate.

Answer (score 1):

DTD(Document Type Definition) is define structure and validity of XML.you need to link DTD into XML by using `<!doctype root_element_name system/public location>`